Passing @ObservedObject data to child views with @State
Having some trouble with Swift @State / @Published / @ObservedObject, hoping to get some help here!
I have a model (Model) which contains a list of recipes as @Published var recipes: [Recipe](). Recipe is a struct.
I have a view which renders a list of recipes, this view is called RecipesView and each list item is rendered in another view called RecipeCardView.
Model:
@Published var recipes = [Recipe]()

...

func fetchRecipes() async throws {
    // do the fetch...

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.recipes = recipes
    }
}

RecipesView looks like this:
@ObservedObject var model: Model

...

ForEach(model.recipes) { recipe in
    ZStack {
        RecipeCardView(model: Model, recipe: recipe)
        NavigationLink(destination: RecipeContentView(model: model, recipe: recipe)) {
            EmptyView()
        }
        .opacity(0)
    }
}

RecipeCardView looks like this:
@ObservedObject var model: Model
@State var recipe: Recipe

Within the RecipeContentView, users can view full recipes and update their content, specifically the recipe's title, which makes an update in the database.
After updating a recipe's title and navigating back to the list view (RecipesView), the list content is not updated. I think this is because every child view down the line has a variable @State var recipe: Recipe, which I think is making copies of the recipe over and over, and the changes are never propagated... that's fine. I can figure that out once I have a better understanding of Swift state management.
The bigger problem is that even after the view model makes another call to the database and updates its own list of recipes (using model.fetchRecipes()), the display still does not update.
Why is this happening?
If I change RecipeCardView to use var recipe: Recipe instead of @State var recipe: Recipe, it actually does work - but, at least with my current implementation, I need that to be a @State variable because I'm calling some mutating functions on it in that view (there's a button to "favorite" a recipe, which calls a mutating func toggleFavorite())
This leads me to believe that when the recipe is copied in RecipeCardView (because of @State), that copy takes precedence over whatever data is coming from the parent view, i.e. even when the RecipesView is re-rendered, the old instance of RecipeCardView and all of its data is re-used.
What is the best solution here?
Should I not be passing recipes down to child views with @State at all? In that case, how should I manage updates to recipes (toggling favorite in the RecipeCardView or editing content in RecipeContentView)?
Should I just pass around recipe IDs to child views, and have them filter out model.recipes to find the target recipe?
Thanks in advance!

@State is for for state local to the view. You should use @Binding.

State should always be private

In addition to the need to learn @Binding, it's a bad idea to name your Views with model names, e.g. your RecipeView. Also, you should only pass into the View the data it needs not whole objects which is what bindings help with.

You should use Binding in order to update a recipe from subview
Here is first aproach, which RecipeView don't know about ViewModel.
struct Recipe: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String = ""
    var isFavorite = true
}

struct Defaults {
    static let reipces = [
        Recipe(name: "pasta", isFavorite: false),
        Recipe(name: "rice", isFavorite: true),
        Recipe(name: "noodle", isFavorite: true)
    ]
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data = Defaults.reipces
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<vm.data.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    RecipeView(recipe: $vm.data[index])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RecipeView: View {
    @Binding var recipe: Recipe
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            Text(recipe.name)
            Text("\(recipe.isFavorite)")
            Button(action: {
                recipe.isFavorite.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Toggle")
            })
        }
        
    }
}

Another aproach could be let RecipeView interact with ViewModel
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(vm.data, id: \.self) { recipe in
                    RecipeView(vm: vm,recipe: recipe)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RecipeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
    var recipe: Recipe
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            Text(recipe.name)
            Text("\(recipe.isFavorite)")
            Button(action: {
                vm.toggleRecipe(recipe: recipe)
            }, label: {
                Text("Toggle")
            })
        }
        
    }
}


You should not use ForEach(0..<vm.data.count, id: \.self) with index, nor
ForEach(vm.data, id: \.self) with .self, this is not good practice.

I agree with you It is not a good practice but here I try to demo the an aproach to pass a binding to subview. But about performance perspective, I think that 2 approach ForEach will be the same

You should watch "Demystify SwiftUI"
